# WC_Order does not return the product id by get_items()

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have tried to get the product id and the product name by the following code:

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $order_id = $query->posts[0]->ID;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
}

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        $product = wc_get_product( $item_id );
        $product_name = $item['name'];
    }
```

In the above code I got the product name, but the it is return 0 for $product_id. Is there any other method for this?

I can't find any solution for this.

My Edited Version:

When I tried this:

```
$order_id = $query->posts[0]->ID;
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();

foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $item_id = $item['product_id'];
    $product_name = $item['name'];
    print_r( $item ); exit;
}
```

I got this array:

```
WC_Order_Item_Product Object
(
    [extra_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 0
            [variation_id] => 0
            [quantity] => 1
            [tax_class] => 
            [subtotal] => 0
            [subtotal_tax] => 0
            [total] => 0
            [total_tax] => 0
            [taxes] => Array
                (
                    [subtotal] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [total] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [data:protected] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 684
            [name] => Dark Skirt "Erebos" - Large, White
            [product_id] => 0
            [variation_id] => 0
            [quantity] => 1
            [tax_class] => 
            [subtotal] => 19
            [subtotal_tax] => 0
            [total] => 19
            [total_tax] => 0
            [taxes] => Array
                (
                    [total] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [subtotal] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [cache_group:protected] => order-items
    [meta_type:protected] => order_item
    [object_type:protected] => order_item
    [id:protected] => 1
    [changes:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [object_read:protected] => 1
    [default_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 0
            [name] => 
            [product_id] => 0
            [variation_id] => 0
            [quantity] => 1
            [tax_class] => 
            [subtotal] => 0
            [subtotal_tax] => 0
            [total] => 0
            [total_tax] => 0
            [taxes] => Array
                (
                    [subtotal] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [total] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [data_store:protected] => WC_Data_Store Object
        (
            [instance:WC_Data_Store:private] => WC_Order_Item_Product_Data_Store Object
                (
                    [internal_meta_keys:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => _order_id
                            [1] => _name
                            [2] => _product_id
                            [3] => _variation_id
                            [4] => _quantity
                            [5] => _tax_class
                            [6] => _subtotal
                            [7] => _subtotal_tax
                            [8] => _total
                            [9] => _total_tax
                            [10] => _taxes
                            [11] => _product_id
                            [12] => _variation_id
                            [13] => _qty
                            [14] => _tax_class
                            [15] => _line_subtotal
                            [16] => _line_subtotal_tax
                            [17] => _line_total
                            [18] => _line_tax
                            [19] => _line_tax_data
                        )

                    [meta_type:protected] => order_item
                    [object_id_field_for_meta:protected] => order_item_id
                )

            [stores:WC_Data_Store:private] => Array
                (
                    [coupon] => WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT
                    [customer] => WC_Customer_Data_Store
                    [customer-download] => WC_Customer_Download_Data_Store
                    [customer-session] => WC_Customer_Data_Store_Session
                    [order] => WC_Order_Data_Store_CPT
                    [order-refund] => WC_Order_Refund_Data_Store_CPT
                    [order-item] => WC_Order_Item_Data_Store
                    [order-item-coupon] => WC_Order_Item_Coupon_Data_Store
                    [order-item-fee] => WC_Order_Item_Fee_Data_Store
                    [order-item-product] => WC_Order_Item_Product_Data_Store
                    [order-item-shipping] => WC_Order_Item_Shipping_Data_Store
                    [order-item-tax] => WC_Order_Item_Tax_Data_Store
                    [payment-token] => WC_Payment_Token_Data_Store
                    [product] => WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT
                    [product-grouped] => WC_Product_Grouped_Data_Store_CPT
                    [product-variable] => WC_Product_Variable_Data_Store_CPT
                    [product-variation] => WC_Product_Variation_Data_Store_CPT
                    [shipping-zone] => WC_Shipping_Zone_Data_Store
                )

            [current_class_name:WC_Data_Store:private] => WC_Order_Item_Product_Data_Store
            [object_type:WC_Data_Store:private] => order-item-product
        )

    [meta_data:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Of you see the [data:protected] array, you can see this where the [product_id] is 0. That is the problem I guess. But what is the solution for this?

Comment: I have tried this but this is also not working. See above my edited vesion.

Comment: To access the protected data use `$item->get_data();` method … See it on: [How to get WooCommerce order details on Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344) … This give you an accessible array (not protected)

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product = $item->get_product();
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
}
```

Comment: It is giving a fatal error like "Call to a member function get_id()". So it is not working and i tried this before. Did you try this before ?

Comment: yes... what version is your woocommerce @Ranjit?? if below 3.0 use `$product->id` instead

Comment: It is the latest (Version 3.1.2). Still not working.